# Extracting the SHA-1 API key to xml

Tags: android

I want to create a new xml document called api_key.xml.
This will allow me to add it to gitignore.
Then I need to call the key stored in the xml from the manifest.

2 problems.
1.  Android studio appears not to detect my new xml file

> ```
>         Cannot resolve symbol '@api_key/key_value' less... (Ctrl+F1)
> ```
>
> Validates resource references inside Android XML files.

Huh?

2.
I don't know what format to store it in my xml under.  As it's a mix of letter and numbers I have guessed string

Here's where it's called from in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="@api_key/key_value"/>
```

Here's api_key.xml (some letters changed)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="key_value">AIzaSyA3Y7KxkXXXXXXXXyqRMiJLeaz2QdeLm7Vo</string>
</resources>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you need to use String.xml where as you have to decleare keyvalue in string.xml then in manifest in side metadata android:value="@string/key_value"  this line to get string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this statement

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="@string/key_value"/>
```